# newfloat, newname, how do I insert a dot?

Tags: floats

I use

```
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{myfig}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{myfig}{myText}
```

I wish to insert a dot after the numbering of the newfloat: `myText N.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the newly defined float `myfig` belongs a counter named `myfig`. Its representation is printed with the command `\thmyfig` which defaults to `\arabic{myfig}`. *i.e.*, the counter number as arabic numeral. You just have to redefine `\themyfig` to also contain the dot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{myfig}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{myfig}{myText}
\renewcommand*\themyfig{\arabic{myfig}.}

\begin{document}

\begin{myfig}
  la la la
  \caption{Foo Bar}
\end{myfig}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. It works with `\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[ruled]{labelsep=period}`  too.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention the `caption` package in your question, did you? ;)

Comment: you are correct, it was a later discovery :-)